# Laravel Output 1 result from hasmany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have a hasmany relationship on my model and I'm trying to output just the one result, i have a product category which can display only one product image.

I have two tables.

```
1 = Product
2 = ProductPhotos
```

I've tried outputting the one photo like

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<img src="{{ $product->photos->first() }}">
@endforeach
```

I have the following relationship setup in my product model

```
public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductPhoto', 'product_id');
    }
```

but this doesnt work.

Comment: Can you please give more details? Like how you implemented your relationship, what are the columns and names that you are using to build the relationship, etc

:)

Comment: If the product can only have one image, then wouldn't it be a `hasOne` relationship? Anyway, if your relationship is defined properly (probably best to include it in question) I believe you need to call the photo like `$product->photos()->first()` (note the parenthesis since you're calling a method on the model).

Comment: Thanks @camelCase that sorted it for me.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Added as answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the parenthesis for the method. It should be:

```
$product->photos()->first();
```

Which will allow Eloquent to access the `photos` method in the `Product` model.